# How to assign values to var oop javascript from Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

how to assign values to var oop javascript from ajax request???

```
function getJSON(url) {
return  $.ajax({
url: url,
type: 'get',
success: function(response){
response.w_v;
}
});
}
function Person(){
this.name = getJSON('proprieta_vetrina.php');
console.log(this.name);
}
const obj = new Person();
console.log(obj.name);
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Hi nacho, welcome to stackoverflow. Could you post more code please, try to tell us what exactly you're trying to achieve and clarify your question since it is hard to get what you want to ask exactly? Where is variable oop located?

Comment: my object json is {"w_v":1280,"w_y":720}

Answer (score 0):

[it's work!! <-- link code --> is my modification ok but i need call the object ouside the function is possible this??](https://codepen.io/ignacio-olivieri/pen/jOEdOzm)

```
function Person(valor){
this.name = valor
alert(this.name);
}

function test(url){

$.ajax({
url: url,
type: 'get',
success: function(response){
var valor = response.w_v;
const obj = new Person(valor);

},
error: function(e){
  alert("error");
}
});

}

test('https://next.json-generator.com/api/json/get/4kqyRw--d');
```

how to do this:

const obj = new Person();

**alert(obj.name); how do this ????**

Comment: if you look this code work but i create the object in test method --- how to call the obejct at last line of code? instead of test('http://......xxx');  i need call constant obj = new Person(); and later cosole.log(obj.name); is posible this?? i work with php and its wor but when i write the same in javascript this dont work friends :(